# SQL How do you get the earnings in a year (revenue-expenses) without manually inserting the year?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, datetime, union

My code looks like this for now:

```
Select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d),
                    (Select SUM(s.serv_p) 
                    FROM customer_orders co
                    INNER JOIN co_service cs ON co.cust_ordr_id = cs.cust_ordr_id 
                    INNER JOIN service s ON cs.serv_id = s.serv_id
                    WHERE co.cust_ordr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do)= 2019
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do))
                    -
                    (Select SUM(s.serv_p)
                    FROM customer_orders co
                    INNER JOIN co_service cs ON co.cust_ordr_id = cs.cust_ordr_id 
                    INNER JOIN service s ON cs.serv_id = s.serv_id
                    WHERE co.cust_ordr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do) = 2019
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do))
                    -
                    ((Select SUM(e.eqp_pp)
                    FROM equipment e
                    INNER JOIN equipment_type y on y.eqp_t_id = e.eqp_t_id
                    WHERE e.eqp_delete_ind = 'False' and y.eqp_t_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.eqp_pd)=2019)
                    +
                    (SELECT SUM((d.prod_qty_ds)*(p.prod_up))
                    FROM product p
                    INNER JOIN delivery d ON p.prod_id = d.prod_id
                    WHERE d.dlvr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d)=2019
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d))
                    +
                    (SELECT 12*SUM(p.pos_sal)
                    FROM employee e
                    INNER JOIN positions p ON p.pos_id = e.pos_id
                    WHERE e.emp_delete_ind = 'False'))
                    FROM delivery d
                    WHERE d.dlvr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d)=2019
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d)
                    UNION
                    Select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d),
                    (Select SUM(s.serv_p) 
                    FROM customer_orders co
                    INNER JOIN co_service cs ON co.cust_ordr_id = cs.cust_ordr_id 
                    INNER JOIN service s ON cs.serv_id = s.serv_id
                    WHERE co.cust_ordr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do)= 2020
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do))
                    -
                    (Select SUM(s.serv_p)
                    FROM customer_orders co
                    INNER JOIN co_service cs ON co.cust_ordr_id = cs.cust_ordr_id 
                    INNER JOIN service s ON cs.serv_id = s.serv_id
                    WHERE co.cust_ordr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do) = 2020
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do))
                    -
                    ((Select SUM(e.eqp_pp)
                    FROM equipment e
                    INNER JOIN equipment_type y on y.eqp_t_id = e.eqp_t_id
                    WHERE e.eqp_delete_ind = 'False' and y.eqp_t_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.eqp_pd)=2020)
                    +
                    (SELECT SUM((d.prod_qty_ds)*(p.prod_up))
                    FROM product p
                    INNER JOIN delivery d ON p.prod_id = d.prod_id
                    WHERE d.dlvr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d)=2020
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d))
                    +
                    (SELECT 12*SUM(p.pos_sal)
                    FROM employee e
                    INNER JOIN positions p ON p.pos_id = e.pos_id
                    WHERE e.emp_delete_ind = 'False'))
                    FROM delivery d
                    WHERE d.dlvr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d)=2020
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d)
                    UNION
                    Select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d),
                    (Select SUM(s.serv_p) 
                    FROM customer_orders co
                    INNER JOIN co_service cs ON co.cust_ordr_id = cs.cust_ordr_id 
                    INNER JOIN service s ON cs.serv_id = s.serv_id
                    WHERE co.cust_ordr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do)= 2021
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do))
                    -
                    (Select SUM(s.serv_p)
                    FROM customer_orders co
                    INNER JOIN co_service cs ON co.cust_ordr_id = cs.cust_ordr_id 
                    INNER JOIN service s ON cs.serv_id = s.serv_id
                    WHERE co.cust_ordr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do) = 2021
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do))
                    -
                    ((Select SUM(e.eqp_pp)
                    FROM equipment e
                    INNER JOIN equipment_type y on y.eqp_t_id = e.eqp_t_id
                    WHERE e.eqp_delete_ind = 'False' and y.eqp_t_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.eqp_pd)=2021)
                    +
                    (SELECT SUM((d.prod_qty_ds)*(p.prod_up))
                    FROM product p
                    INNER JOIN delivery d ON p.prod_id = d.prod_id
                    WHERE d.dlvr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d)=2021
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d))
                    +
                    (SELECT 12*SUM(p.pos_sal)
                    FROM employee e
                    INNER JOIN positions p ON p.pos_id = e.pos_id
                    WHERE e.emp_delete_ind = 'False'))
                    FROM delivery d
                    WHERE d.dlvr_delete_ind = 'False' and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d)=2021
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dlvr_d)
```

---

Annual EARNINGS = Annual Revenue (Sum of Service Transactions) - Annual Expenses (Salary for 12 months + Expenses from Purchasing Products through delivery + Expenses from purchasing a new equipment)

I get the revenue by joining the service table (contains the services provided by the shop) a co_service table (services availed per transaction) and the customer order table (for transactions) then i extracted them by year to get the annual value

expenses for purchasing come from a delivery table which records incoming product deliveries, and an equipment type table records the kinds of equipments (dryer, washer, etc), while equipments are the individual units of equipment (washer-01, washer-02, etc)

and lastly positions table contains the salary for each employee position

Comment: What is the relation between `employee` and `positions` tables with `delivery` table? Are they connected with date?

Comment: Next question, Why you repeat `Select SUM(s.serv_p) FROM customer_orders co ...` two times for each year `(Select SUM(s.serv_p) FROM customer_orders co ...) - (Select SUM(s.serv_p) FROM customer_orders co ...)` this result always zero because query has been duplicated

Comment: Please provide more information about your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by making yourself a subquery that contains a row for every year in your database. In your case it seems likely that, between your `delivery` and `customer_orders` tables, every interesting year shows up. So do this. It gets you a virtual table with one row per year.

```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dlvr_d) yr
     FROM delivery
    UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cust_ordr_do) yr
    FROM customer_orders
```

You can then write your queries to start with that subquery, and LEFT JOIN the other stuff you want to it.  Something like this might work.

```sql
WITH years AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dlvr_d) yr
     FROM delivery
    UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cust_ordr_do) yr
    FROM customer_orders
)
SELECT years.yr, serv.serv_p
 FROM years
 LEFT JOIN (
    Select SUM(s.serv_p) serv_p, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_order_do) yr
      FROM customer_orders co
     INNER JOIN co_service cs ON co.cust_ordr_id = cs.cust_ordr_id 
     INNER JOIN service s ON cs.serv_id = s.serv_id
     WHERE co.cust_ordr_delete_ind = 'False'
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM co.cust_ordr_do)
 ) serv ON years.yr = serv.yr
```

That will get you a result set with a row for every year. It will have a column that's either null (meaning no results for the year) or a useful value from the query you showed.

I don't understand your query well enough to refactor the whole thing, sorry to say.